# ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:2633)

Tags: python, ubuntu, ssl, ftp, sftp

I run this python code

```
from ftplib import FTP_TLS
ftps = FTP_TLS(timeout=100)           
ftps.connect("213.226.112.19", 21)
ftps.auth()
ftps.prot_p()
ftps.login('user', 'password')
```

But get this error

```
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:2633)
```

It is ok, when I try to connect via FileZilla or browser.
What can be the problem?

Comment: Works for me. Server supports TLS 1.3 and TLS 1.2 but not lower. Please provide the output of `python -c 'import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)'`

Comment: I checked it, it is version OpenSSL 1.1.1f actually. Could you say please, how can I update it? I'm beginner, thanks

Comment: OpenSSL version is fine. Same es I use. Something else is wrong in your setup. Are there any firewalls or similar in your network which might infer with the traffic?